# Can the player review their work in Zen Bound 2?

Tags: achievements, zen-bound-2

An achievement within **Zen Bound 2**, called *Meticulous Detonator*, involves triggering all the paint-bombs in each level within a collection of levels called the *Tree of Focus*. While attempting to obtain the achievement, I've completed each level in the collection, triggering paint-bombs where I've found them, only to become stymied when the achievement didn't pop. It's possible there was something I've overlooked in one of the levels with the low-contrast paints, or that one of my ropes slipped off a nail when I was tying off my rope.

What I'd like to know is; Is there a way to quickly review my completed level solutions and check out my rope-wrapped wood carvings, so I can quickly find the level where I didn't catch each paint-bomb? Is there some indicator I'm missing? Or do I have to go through them all again and again, hoping beyond hope that someday the achievement will see fit to ding?

I mean, there's *meticulous*, and then there's *anal*... But I guess nobody said Zen would be easy.